# How can i check and inform the user when connected to the ftp server successfully?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ftp

In this button2 click event i'm starting a backgroundworker that will retrieve all the directories and files from my ftp server and will display them in real time on a treeView.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label13.Text = "Retrieving ftp content please wait";
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = false;
            toolStripProgressBar2.Visible = true;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(txtHost.Text);
        }
```

In the backgoundworker1 do work event i did:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            var root = Convert.ToString(e.Argument);  // txtHost.Text;

            searched_until_now_dirs = 0;
            total_dirs = 1;
            max_percentage = 0;
            last_update = DateTime.Now;
            directories_real_time = new TreeNode();
            var dirNode = CreateDirectoryNode(root, "root",1);

            e.Result = dirNode;
        }
```

The method CreateDirectoryNode

```
private int total_dirs;
        private int searched_until_now_dirs;
        private int max_percentage;
        private TreeNode directories_real_time;
        private string SummaryText;

        private TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(string path, string name , int recursive_levl )
        {
            var directoryNode = new TreeNode(name);
            var directoryListing = GetDirectoryListing(path);

        }
```

And GetDirectoryListing:

```
public IEnumerable<FTPListDetail> GetDirectoryListing(string rootUri)
        {
            var CurrentRemoteDirectory = rootUri;
            var result = new StringBuilder();
            var request = GetWebRequest(WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails, CurrentRemoteDirectory);
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    while (line != null)
                    {
                        result.Append(line);
                        result.Append("\n");
                        line = reader.ReadLine();
                    }
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.ToString()))
                    {
                        return new List<FTPListDetail>();
                    }
                    result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf("\n"), 1);
                    var results = result.ToString().Split('\n');
                    string regex =
                        @"^" +               //# Start of line
                        @"(?<dir>[\-ld])" +          //# File size          
                        @"(?<permission>[\-rwx]{9})" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                        @"\s+" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                        @"(?<filecode>\d+)" +
                        @"\s+" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                        @"(?<owner>\w+)" +
                        @"\s+" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                        @"(?<group>\w+)" +
                        @"\s+" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                        @"(?<size>\d+)" +
                        @"\s+" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                        @"(?<month>\w{3})" +          //# Month (3 letters)   \n
                        @"\s+" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                        @"(?<day>\d{1,2})" +        //# Day (1 or 2 digits) \n
                        @"\s+" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                        @"(?<timeyear>[\d:]{4,5})" +     //# Time or year        \n
                        @"\s+" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                        @"(?<filename>(.*))" +            //# Filename            \n
                        @"$";                //# End of line

                    var myresult = new List<FTPListDetail>();
                    foreach (var parsed in results)
                    {
                        var split = new Regex(regex)
                            .Match(parsed);
                        var dir = split.Groups["dir"].ToString();
                        var permission = split.Groups["permission"].ToString();
                        var filecode = split.Groups["filecode"].ToString();
                        var owner = split.Groups["owner"].ToString();
                        var group = split.Groups["group"].ToString();
                        var filename = split.Groups["filename"].ToString();
                        var size = split.Groups["size"].Length;
                        myresult.Add(new FTPListDetail()
                        {
                            Dir = dir,
                            Filecode = filecode,
                            Group = group,
                            FullPath = CurrentRemoteDirectory + "/" + filename,
                            Name = filename,
                            Owner = owner,
                            Permission = permission,
                        });
                    };
                    return myresult;
                }
            }
        }
```

And last where i'm doing the ftp request:

```
private FtpWebRequest GetWebRequest(string method, string uri)
        {
            Uri serverUri = new Uri("ftp://"+ uri);
            if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
            {
                return null;
            }
            var reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(serverUri);
            reqFTP.Method = method;
            reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
            reqFTP.Proxy = null;
            reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
            reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
            return reqFTP;
        }
```

When i'm clicking the button and start the backgroundworker it takes some seconds untill it's starting to retrieve the directories and files and display them on the treeView.

What i want to do now is somehow in the GetwebRequest i think in this method to wait untill i get connected successfully to the ftp server and only then to start rerieving the directories and files.
If there was an erorr/problem connecting the server display it to the user with a label for example and stop the backgroundworker.

But the whole idea is to give the user some message if he got connected to the ftp server successfully or not before the operation started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run into a error in your `GetWebReqeust` your already returning a NULL value meaning you cannot get a working connection. In your `GetDirectoryListning` you should catch this NULL value and throw it up to your background DoWork event. Inside there you could check for the null and if needed call the .cancel method on the background worker. this will complete the dowork event and trigger the RunWorkerComplete event.

then use the RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler to set the label to a value you like to display when the connection failed. Microsoft wrote a example how to do this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx)